# Part-of-speech tag without context using nltk

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

Is there an easy way to determine the most likely part of speech tag for a given word **without context** using nltk. Or if not using any other tool / dataset.

I tried to use wordnet, but it seems that the sysnets are not ordered by likelihood.

```
>>> wn.synsets('says')

[Synset('say.n.01'), Synset('state.v.01'), ...]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to try tagging without the context, you are looking for some sort of a unigram tagger, aka `looup tagger`. **A unigram tagger tags a word solely based on the frequency of the tag given a word**. So it avoids the context heuristics, however for any tagging task you must have data. And for the unigrams you need annotated data to train it. See the `lookup tagger` in the nltk tutorial http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch05.html.

Below is another way of training/testing an unigram tagger in `NLTK`

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import brown
>>> from nltk import UnigramTagger as ut
>>> brown_sents = brown.tagged_sents()
# Split the data into train and test sets.
>>> train = int(len(brown_sents)*90/100) # use 90% for training
# Trains the tagger
>>> uni_tag = ut(brown_sents[:train]) # this will take some time, ~1-2 mins
# Tags a random sentence
>>> uni_tag.tag ("this is a foo bar sentence .".split())
[('this', 'DT'), ('is', 'BEZ'), ('a', 'AT'), ('foo', None), ('bar', 'NN'), ('sentence', 'NN'), ('.', '.')]
# Test the taggers accuracy.
>>> uni_tag.evaluate(brown_sents[train+1:]) # evaluate on 10%, will also take ~1-2 mins
0.8851469586629643
```

I wouldn't recommend using WordNet for pos tagging because just are sooo many words that are still has no entry in wordnet. But you can take a look at using lemma frequencies in wordnet, see [How to get the wordnet sense frequency of a synset in NLTK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15551195/how-to-get-the-wordnet-sense-frequency-of-a-synset-in-nltk). These frequencies are based on the SemCor corpus (http://www.cse.unt.edu/~rada/downloads.html)

Comment: "A unigram tagger tags a word solely based on the frequency of the tag given a word." Ideally it would also look at the word endings, for smoothing.