# WordNet(JWI MIT) : How to find High Frequency words list?

Tags: dictionary, words, wordnet, jwi

Using **JWI MIT interface libraries** http://projects.csail.mit.edu/jwi/ , how can I find the list of most frequently used English words in daily life from WordNet api (http://wordnet.princeton.edu/)? Is there any way I can accomplish this if API initially does not provide this?

Because initially API does not filter words on a level.

Comment: Google? There are lots of lists like these, and the top-100 looks pretty stable across them.

Comment: Are you saying that I search them externally and find out them from API using my own code?

Comment: Sorry, do you mean the other way around? Using WordNet to find the most frequent words in your corpus?

Comment: Yes, exactly. If it does so then I would like to know.

Answer (score 1):

WordNet comes with usage word counts, but the man page describes them as unreliable and not updated since 2001:
   http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/man/cntlist.5WN.html

The answer to a similar question also points out how the data is not very useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12376620/841830

I realize this is not answering your question, but I think you should regard WordNet as not having any word usage count information, and instead get that information from a different source. (If you want word usage counts for a particular corpus, not generally, that should be its own question, but basically WordNet is not the tool for that job.)