# AttributeError: 'FreqDist' object has no attribute 'inc'

Tags: python, python-2.7, attributes, nltk

I am a beginner in Python and NLTK. I am trying to run the following code from a tutorial:

```
from nltk.corpus import gutenberg
from nltk import FreqDist

fd = FreqDist()

for word in gutenberg.words('austen-sense.txt'):
    fd.inc(word)
```

If I run this I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'FreqDist' object has no attribute 'inc'
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should do it like so:

```
fd[word] += 1
```

But usually FreqDist is used like this:

```
fd = FreqDist(my_text)
```

Also look at the examples here:

http://www.nltk.org/book/ch01.html

Comment: There's a wiki page, https://github.com/nltk/nltk/wiki/Porting-your-code-to-NLTK-3.0, listing the interface changes

Answer (score 6):

For people looking for how to change the book example to NLTK 3.0:

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import brown

suffix_fdist = nltk.FreqDist()
for word in brown.words():
    word = word.lower()
    suffix_fdist[word[-1:]] +=1
    suffix_fdist[word[-2:]] +=1
    suffix_fdist[word[-3:]] +=1
common_suffixes = []
for suffix in suffix_fdist.most_common(100):
    common_suffixes.append(str(suffix.__getitem__(0)))
print common_suffixes
```

Answer (score 3):

Some of the features have been deprecated.

The code in question does work on version nltk 2.0.4

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nltk/2.0.4

To install version 2.0.4 follow:

> wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/nltk/nltk-2.0.4.zip#md5=cbd04d8635f1358a69a38c4774be029c
>
> 7z x nltk-2.0.4.zip
>
> cd nltk-2.0.4/
>
> python setup.py install

To check which version is installed run the following:

> pip search nltk

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Latest version of nltk doesn't have inc. Rather I used update.

```
from nltk.corpus import gutenberg
from nltk import FreqDist

fd = FreqDist()

for word in gutenberg.words('austen-sense.txt'):
    fd.update([word])
```

The update takes iterable item. So make sure you are passing iterable item in update function.