# 'inc' object with NLTK for py 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, nltk

I have only just downloaded nltk this morning and have already run into a reoccurring problem with my code.

I get,

```
AttributeError: 'FreqDist' object has no attribute 'inc'
```

I had the same error with this code,

```
for word in gutenberg.words(’austen-persuasion.txt’):
    fd.inc(word)
```

but simply changed it to

```
fd[word] += 1
```

However, where do I go when faced with the below code?

```
for word in gutenberg.words(u'austen-persuasion.txt'):
    cfd[prev_word].inc(word)
    prev_word = word
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a nested FreqDist.
Try changing

```
    cfd[prev_word].inc(word)
```

to

```
    cfd[prev_word][word] += 1
```

Comment: That did the job, however, in general how do I get by/around this FreqDist module? As I am having a similar issue with `lwords = cfd[word].samples()` line

Comment: `FreqDist` is a pretty integral class in NLTK, you won't get around it, I'm afraid. Unfortunately, NLTK's updates are not always backwards-compatible, so code from an earlier version might not run properly with your recent installation – as you just had to learn the hard way. `FreqDist.inc()` is also discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25827058/attributeerror-freqdist-object-has-no-attribute-inc).