# count the number of words in wordnet using java

Tags: java, wordnet

I am using wordnet 3.0 and the jwnl API.

I want to find the number of words in wordnet which have more of one sense with java. the problem is that i don't know how to browse wordnet and get more of one word.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928704/how-do-i-find-the-frequency-count-of-a-word-in-english-using-wordnet

Comment: i'm looking for finding a why to extract all the words(verbs, adverbs, nouns, ...) of wordnet and not just one or two. and i want to do that using java and the jwnl API.